# Forceful login in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have an iPad app and its used in a hotel for guests. So multiple users use the app through Facebook login and after the usage I need to logout the user from the app. So the next user will have the login screen again. I'm doing this in logout process and when I call the login function Its not giving the login screen. Instead it give me the already authorized screen. (With ok and cancel button). Please help to resolve this issue.

**To login:**

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile"], fromViewController: self, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
if error != nil {
    print("error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
} else if result.isCancelled {
    print("user cancelled")
} else {
    print("success")
}
})
```

**To Logout :**

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)

let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
for cookie in storage.cookies! {
    storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
}
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: You logout your FBSDKLoginManager class session, but not logout in browser.

Comment: Use Device Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It will always give you an already authorized screen because Facebook is not responsible to logout from the Safari browser.*

You are logged out from the login manager it is fine.

For this situation you can use the `loginBehavior` property of `FBSDKLoginManager`

You have to set the behavior to the `Web` it will open popup to login.

```
let fbManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
fbManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
fbManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

[image]

You can do the logout from the manager as per your need.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @CharithNidarsha Welcome anytime :)

Comment: This way works. Once the user tries to re-login, it comes up with that "already authorized ..." but when you press okay, it closes itself and the result isn't canceled. I just hope that user doesn't have to sign in..

Answer (score 0):

clear your facebook token from ios like this... this make user to login every time in app

```
ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        NSArray *fbAccounts = [store accountsWithAccountType:[store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook]];
        for (ACAccount *fb in fbAccounts) {
            [store renewCredentialsForAccount:fb completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {

            }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using their custom button class FBSDKLoginButton on a view. You should only enter the protected page on view will appear if the currentAccessToken is not nil. This will prevent showing the first view for a few miliseconds. As you can see, I embeded my viewControllers in a NaviguationController.

UIView with custom class in the login view :

[image]

ViewWillAppear :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        loginFacebook(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString,
            userId: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)
        self.enterProtectedPage();
    }
}
```

ViewDidLoad :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginBtn.delegate = self
        loginBtn.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_relationship_details"];
}
```

login button click action :

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if (error != nil) {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
       return
    }

    if let _ = result.token {
       loginFacebook(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString,
       userId: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().userID)
       self.enterProtectedPage();
    }
 }
```

enter protected page :

```
func enterProtectedPage() {
     let protectedPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProtectedPageViewController") as!
        ProtectedPageViewController
        let protectedPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: protectedPage)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = protectedPageNav
}
```

logout action on the protected page :

```
@IBAction func btnLogoutClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
        let loginPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as!ViewController
        let loginPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginPage)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginPageNav
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me 
**For objective-C**

1st Define

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)FBSDKLoginManager *login;
```

Then Use this method.

```
-(void)logoutFromFacebook{

   if(self.login){

      [self.login logOut];
  }else{
      self.login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
      [self.login logOut];
  }

}
```

**For Swift**

```
var login: FBSDKLoginManager?

func FBSDKLoginManager () {
  if self.login != nil {
    self.login.logout()
  }else {
    self.login = self.login()
    self.login.logout()
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.